# Show android emulators when running tests via gradle managed devices

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso, gradle-managed-device

When running android espresso tests via [gradle managed devices](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices), i.e. by running:

```
./gradlew pixel4api30DebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.aaa.bbb.ccc.Suites.TestSuite -Pandroid.experimental.androidTest.numManagedDeviceShards=3
```

Is it possible to have it display the emulators while running the tests so that you are able to see what is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `--enable-display` switch:

```
./gradlew pixel4api30DebugAndroidTest --enable-display
```

But keep in mind that this will not work with ATD images.

Comment: Sawweetttt....THANK YOU!!

Comment: how did you know that was a possible option to use?  Is there a list of options somewhere that I can reference?

Comment: Seem like Google does not provide much information (as always). Found it in the gradle package `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.ManagedDeviceInstrumentationTestTask`  

    @Option(
            option="enable-display",
            description = "Adding this option will display the emulator while testing, instead" +
                "of running the tests on a headless emulator.")
        fun setDisplayEmulatorOption(value: Boolean) = enableEmulatorDisplay.set(value)`